# What is the effect of setting `number of processors` in msconfig (and its potential interactions with steam downloads)?

Tags: windows-10, boot, cpu, performance, steam

I have been having an ongoing issue where steam causes my entire computer to hang and stutter when downloading a game.  The problem is so bad it makes the PC unusable due to the incredible amount of lag.

After looking online for fixes, I found a few that all seem to revolve around CPU timing and the processor clock (`bcdedit /set useplatformclock true` and various other tweaks).  The only one that worked for me however, was to set the number of processors in the boot menu.

```
msconfig > boot > advanced options > check number of processors box > set value to 4 (# physical cores)
```

After doing this everything appears to run fine. I have steam downloading in the background and I am experiencing 0 lag or stutter.

This leads me to my question which is a) what does this setting do and b) why might it have fixed this problem?

After looking online a bit, it appears this setting is related to the number of cores windows uses to boot and is a *limit* on the number of cores it can use while booting.  This confused me, as task manager already shows I have 4 physical cores and 8 total threads, so setting a so called limit of 4 should have changed nothing...

I am also wondering if this will affect my computer's performance in any way (ie limiting cpu usage) or if it just affects boot and is fine to leave on.

For reference, I have an [i7-3770k](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/65523/intel-core-i7-3770k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html) cpu.

---

**Update**

It appears this is disabling some of the cores, and is actually the number of total *threads* allowed, as task manager only shows 2 cores and 4 threads after setting it to `4 processes`.

I am still not sure, however, why disabling half of my cores is necessary to prevent steam downloads from borking my system...

Answer (score 0):

The Number of Processors setting in msconfig is used for debugging Windows and should not be enabled by standard users. Enabling it tells Windows to only allocate for use the specified number of processor threads.
When this checkbox is unchecked, Windows automatically allocates all available processor threads for use.

There have been a number of internet articles and guides claiming performance benefits for manually editing the Number of Processors. These guides are misinformation and can result in lost performance when this option is misconfigured. Furthermore, when a user upgrades to a CPU with more threads, they may forget they limited their number of threads in this setting, resulting in performance loss.

Instead of modifying your system to suite a particular software, you should always report software bugs and performance issues to the developer, such as Steam.